# URL encoding encodes my String twice

Tags: java, android, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a Json String to encode

```
String strMappingList = [{"Id": "67","AccessType": "2"},{"Id": "1111","AccessType": "2"},{"Id": "1166","AccessType": "2"}]
```

When I did url encoding it encodes strMappingList twice

```
try {
    String str = URLEncoder.encode(strMappingList, "utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The above code encode method encode the string only one time  o/p  is                                  %5B%7B%27Id%27%3A+%2767%27%2C%27AccessType%27%3A+%272%27%7D%2C%7B%27Id%27%3A+%271111%27%2C%27AccessType%27%3A+%272%27%7D%2C%7B%27Id%27%3A+%271166%27%2C%27AccessType%27%3A+%272%27%7D%5D

Answer (score 1):

> **Try the code you take in strings file**

**if you get response from server that fine not use in string.xml you use direct**

in string.xml

```
  <string name="urls">[{"Id": "67","AccessType": "2"},{"Id": "1111","AccessType": "2"},{"Id": "1166","AccessType": "2"}]</string>
```

> **Code**

```
String strMappingList = getResources().getString(R.string.urls);

try {
    String str = URLEncoder.encode(strMappingList, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Strings"+str);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> **Output Single time**
>
> %5B%7BId%3A+67%2CAccessType%3A+2%7D%2C%7BId%3A+1111%2CAccessType%3A+2%7D%2C%7BId%3A+1166%2CAccessType%3A+2%7D%5D